# UIScrollView not Working in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

Hi in my app i have a contact form in that i  kept  scroll view for the user to scroll the long content but its not working before the i have used same code for my iphone application but now I'm working on ipad its not working.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;


     - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
     [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 800)];

   }
```

please tell me where I'm doing wrong why its not working.

Thanks.

Comment: is ur content size > scroll view's frame?

Comment: iPad screen size is 1024 if I not mistaken so 1024 > 800 therefor the scrollView doesn't need to scroll as all the content should fit on the screen.

Comment: @ShantiK i give more then frame size its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content size should be greater than the frame size of the scrollview. Only then the scrolling will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // Make scroll view size to main view size   
    scroll.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

    //Double the height of iPad or Iphone
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height*2)];

    //Or
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, your Large Height)];


}
```